# using grep -rl "[SEARCH]" . how can i open each file found in notepad++

Tags: bash, grep, notepad++

I have a grep search command like this:

`grep -rl "<script" .`

The result is something like this:

```
./filename.txt
./filename2.txt
./filename3.txt
```

I want to take each line in the result and open it in Notepad++

I can open a file in Notepad++ with this:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" ./filename.txt`

What would my command line command look like to open each result in notepad?

Comment: On linux you could do `grep -rl "<script" . | xargs notepad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing here on which operating system you are working, but since you use bash and grep, I assume a bash-solution is what you want, i.e. the following may work in your specific bash, seemingly running on Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" $(grep -rl "<script" .)
```

The "trick" being the $(...) which runs the enclosed command and puts individual result lines on the command line. If the resulting file names have characters that are special to bash, you would need a more elaborate solution.

Comment: perfect -- unfortunately file names with spaces break it, but there's only 1 in my results so i can deal with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want Notepad++ to open the files to the line grep matched, you can do

```
for match in $(grep -rn "<script" .); do
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" `echo $match | awk -F":" '{print "-n"$2" "$1}'`
done
```

This will invoke Notepad++ *n* times, where *n* is the number of matches.